# How do you use the Delegate Protocol Pattern with SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, delegates, protocols

So I have one `UIViewController` and two `SKScene`s. The `UIViewController` present the two scenes by rotating the device; `landscape` load `SKScene` 1 and `portrait` load `SKScene` 2 lie this:

```
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        print("TRIGGERED")

        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            print("Landscape")
            presentView(name: "GameScene")
        } else {
            print("Portrait")
            presentView(name: "GameScene2")
        }
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    }

    func presentView(name: String) {
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
              if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: name) {
                  scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                  view.presentScene(scene)
              }
              view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
              view.showsFPS = true
              view.showsNodeCount = true
          }
    }
```

This works fine. My dilema, however, is that I want to implement a delegate-protocol pattern between the two SKScenes `GameScene` and `GameScene2`. The problem is that the `UIViewController` (self) of `SKScene` 1 should be passed as the delegate to the `SKScene` 2. So if the user for instance click something in `landscape` mode (GameScene), som data `String` is passed over to GameScene2 when orientation is changed to `portrait`.

So in `SkScene` 1:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func myProtocolFunc(someString: String)
}

class GameScene: SKScene{

    var myDelegate: MyProtocol!
```

and in the `UIViewController` how do I set the delegate? `scene.myDelegate` doesn't work. `GameScene().myDelegate = GameScene2().self` works but since `view.presentScene(scene)` is used to present the scene that's not relevant. How do I access and set the `delegate`? How do I set up the `delegate-protocol` pattern so that I get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Swift 5**:

```
protocol MyProtocol: AnyObject {
    func myProtocolFunc(someString: String)
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    weak var myDelegate: MyProtocol?

    init(fileNamed: String) {
        super.init(fileNamed: fileNamed)
    }
}
```

Then you have to create the scene object in your presentView method as a GameScene, not a SKScene (as you did). So instead of:

```
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: name) // wrong
```

you have to:

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: name) // correct
```

and then you can easily set the delegate with `scene.myDelegate`

Comment: Ah, thank you! But isn't there a trade off for not using `SKScene(fileNamed: name)`? I mean why isn't that done by defualt?

Comment: Your `GameScene` (You could also name it `MyPersonalGameScene`) is a subclass of `SKScene`. So you have all the functionality the SKScene is providing + your custom stuff from the `GameScene`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you for clearing that out!

Comment: Can I just ask why you use `:AnyObject` and `init(fileNamed String)...`?

Comment: Also how can you use `GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")` and `GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene2")`. Shouldn't you use `GameScene2(fileNamed: "GameScene2")`?

Comment: GameScene is your code. "GameScene" is your layout file.  If this was a board game, think of GameScene as the rules, and "GameScene" as the pieces.  If this was Monopoly, you could have a regular edition, and a Super Mario edition.  Both can use the same rules, but have a completely different look to it.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon you nailed it haha

Comment: Concerning AnyObject: I would suggest you to just accept this for now: Whenever you create your own custom delegate protocol and want to use it in a class, conform the protocol to AnyObject and make the delegate property weak and optional. If you really want to understand it tho read this: https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-anyobject-in-swift