# How do I use the same instance in a delegate protocol pattern?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, delegates, protocols

I recently asked a question on how to use a `protocol` `delegate` pattern here: [How do you use the Delegate Protocol Pattern with SpriteKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769348/how-do-you-use-the-delegate-protocol-pattern-with-spritekit)

And while I got an answer that got me a long way, I don't get it working all the way, and I think it has to do with the fact that I don't (and can't I think) use the same instance when changing `SKView`s. Let me explain.

I have one UIViewController and two `SKScenes`. The UIViewController present the two `scenes` by rotating the device; `landscape` load `SKScene` 1 and portrait load `SKScene` 2 like this:

```
  override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        print("TRIGGERED")

        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            print("Landscape")
            presentView(name: "GameScene")
        } else {
            print("Portrait")
            presentView(name: "GameScene2")
        }
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    }

    func presentView(name: String) {
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
              if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: name) {
                  scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                  view.presentScene(scene)
              }
              view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
              view.showsFPS = true
              view.showsNodeCount = true
          }
    }
```

and in `SKScene` 1:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func myProtocolFunc(someString: String)
}

class GameScene: SKScene{

    var myDelegate: MyProtocol!
```

and in `SKScene` 2:

```
class GameScene2: MyProtocol {
    private var label: SKLabelNode?

    func myProtocolFunc(someString: String) {
        label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        label!.text = someString
        label!.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        addChild(label!)
    }
```

The `SKlabel` isn't updated with the `delegate` value however. An like I said I think this is because I create a new instance of `scene` when loading `SKScene` 2. And that instance don't have the `delegate`. I'm not sure how to work around this though since I need to have a new instance of `SKScene` to load the other scene.

Comment: It is not completely clear to me with where do you set your `myDelegate` property, but you should notice that every time you rotate your device, you create new scene and present it. Every time you present it you have to set its properties the value you need, so maybe on that step there is a problem

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth for you to read into the coordinator pattern https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/71/how-to-use-the-coordinator-pattern-in-ios-apps